# Regex question: Why isn't this matching?

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

I have the following regex: `(?<=\.\d+?)0+(?=\D|$)` I'm running it against a string which contains the following: `SVC~NU^0270~313.3~329.18~~10~~6.00:`

When it runs, it matches the 6.00 (correctly) which my logic then trims by one zero to turn into 6.0.  The regex then runs again (or should) but fails to pick up the 6.0.

I'm by no means an expert on Regex, but my understanding of my expression is that it's looking for a decimal with 1 or more optional (so, really zero or more) digits prior to one or more zeros which are then followed by any non-digit character or the line break.  Assuming that interpretation is correct, I can't see why it wouldn't match on the second pass.  For that matter, I'm not sure why my `Regex.Replace` isn't matching the full 6.00 on the first pass and removing both of the trailing zeros...

Any suggestions?

Comment: This regex is looking for the last zero and if it finds it, it then removes it (therefore a match) - If no second '0' it cannot find that match and therefore fails... [having a closer look for you] to find remedy - What do you need it to return?

Comment: On second thought, @Glycerine is right: it’s not clear what you expect as the final result. My answer will “fix” the expression but the result will be odd (at least to me) since it strips all trailing zeros, leaving just `6.`.

Comment: Ultimately, I do want the decimal removed if there are no digits after it, but I'm relatively confident of my ability to do that- I just couldn't figure out why the single 0 wasn't matching.  Thanks.

Comment: `\.0+(?!\d)|(?<=\.\d*)0+(?!\d)` will do it all in one pass: remove decimals followed only by zeroes, and remove trailing zeroes otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+?` means “match one or more, non-greedy”. You presumably think that it means the same as `*`, i.e. match zero or more times. So the preceding expression `\d` must match *at least once* for your whole expression to match, and that’s no longer the case for the input `6.0`.

Change `+?` to `*` and the expression should work.

Comment: I just tried that, that will strip out any Zeros full stop... therefore `SVC~NU^0270~313.3~329.18~~10~~6.00000000000:` would become `SVC~NU^0270~313.3~329.18~~10~~6.:`

Comment: @Glycerine: Yup, this would change the meaning of the regular expression. Isn’t that what the OP wants? After all, he explicitly *does* want to find `6.0` and strip out the trailing zero.

Comment: Which means that your regex only matches if there are at least two digits after the decimal, and if the last (one-or-more) digits are zero.  It will never match a zero directly after the decimal point.

I think you just need to replace `\d+?` with `\d*`

Comment: @adam-boyers: Uh? That’s exactly what I’m suggesting. Did you perhaps misread something?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(?<=\.\d+?)0*?(?=\D|$)
```

Comment: Notice that this may result in a match of size zero (if there is such a thing in .NET …).

Comment: This change merely allows it to match an empty string when the sequence *doesn't* end with zeroes--and yes, @Konrad, that's perfectly legal.  But it's pointless in this case, since the intent is to remove the trailing zeroes.